# Create virtual subdomain directory in IIS Express in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, virtual-directory

I'm trying to create a subdomain on my localhost on my pc.

The domain that I access currently looks like this:

```
http://localhost:19215
```

For testing purposes I should enable the domain to be accessed like this:

```
mytestname.localhost:19215
```

Or to change the domain to be like this:

```
 mytestname.localhost
```

Either is fine I just can't get it to work.. I have tried editing my applicationhost.config file which looks like this:

```
  <site name="Somesitename" id="3">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="somepath" />
      </application>
   <bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:19215:localhost" />
   <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44343:localhost" />
   </bindings>
 </site>
```

This is what the configuration looks like by default....

I have tried adding a line like this:

```
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:19215:*.localhost" />
```

Which would mean that I can literally enter any URL before the localhost and still make it to work like following:

```
mytestname.localhost:19215
mytestname2.localhost:19215
mytestname4.localhost:19215
mytestname5.localhost:19215
mytestname6.localhost:19215
```

But then  I get an error:

```
localhost refused to connect.
```

The application isn't even showing that it started up...

Can someone help me out with this ? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Guys I realized what I'm looking for is to setup a wilcard subdomain which is available with IIS 10... Does anyone knows how to set it up properly?